# What is a django middleware equivalent in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, django-middleware

Basically, I want to inject some data into ViewData/ViewBag for every single request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC that would be an [action filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs). And if you want to do it globally you could register it as a [global action filter](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx). This way it will apply to all controller actions so that you don't need to decorate them individually.

So your filter could be defined like this:

```
public class GlobalViewBagInjectorActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Foo = "bar";
    }
}
```

and registered in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method in your `Global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new GlobalViewBagInjectorActionFilter());
}
```

Now inside all your views you can use the `ViewBag.Foo` property.

But in most situations [Child Actions](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) are a better alternative than `ViewBag` as they allow you to pass strongly typed view models instead of relying on this weakly typed ViewBag and some magic strings.

Comment: I have seen child actions, but what puts me off is that I still need to define url for it in routing. It does not make sense to me.